# Max switch current

Tags: switches

I am in the process of designing my first PCB and I need to include some switches to open or close a circuit with a max current of 500mA at 5v. I have found a DIP switch that I want to include on the PCB but I am not sure if the switch can support the current of my circuit. The specification of the switch say:

```
Contact Rating: 
   Switch: 25mA @ 24V DC
   Carry: 100mA @ 50V DC
Insulation Resistance: 
   100 MΩ Min. @ 500V DC
Contact Resistance: 
   Initial:50 mΩ typical @ 2-4V DC @ 100mA
   After Life: 100mΩ typical @ 2-4 DC @ 100mA
```

The PDF file is also [here](http://www.e-switch.com/Portals/0/Series_Pdf/KAS.pdf)

So here is the question: When the circuit is closed, is this switch going to support the circuit current? How can I calculate that? Should I take care when the circuit is open?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say no. The specification does not mention anything higher than 100mA. Although these figures are accompanied by a voltage (for instance 50 mΩ at -2-4V) that does not mean that 4V is directly applied to the switch, because then the current would be 4V/50 mΩ = 80A!

The voltages matter in a switch too because the switch experiences the voltage when it is open, and it comes into play at the moment when the contact is being made or broken. Voltage causes arcing of switch contacts. It also plays a role in breaking through the thin film of oxidation. Note how conservative the 24V switch rating is. The current must be only up to 25 mA if you want to open and close the switch at 24V.

Even if you don't plan on changing the switches while current is flowing, the data sheet does not mention anything about carrying more than 100mA.

Idea: use the switches to control transistors to deliver the current.

Comment: Thanks! I am new in the electronics world, and I thought that at lower voltage (5v instead of 50v DC), the switch would support more current. But I think that I should better understand basic electronic :)

Answer (score 3):

Since the switch is rated to switch 25mA, and carry 100mA, I wouldn't trust it to be reliable with your 500 mA current.

I've always considered those DIP switches to be suitable for switching logic signals - I wouldn't use them to switch real power.